# use Dojo to style a programmatically generated combo box

Tags: dojo

I want to set the text size for a programmatically generated combo box using dojo codes below. The width and height work but not the font-size.

```js
var cboState = new ComboBox({
                             id: "usastate",
                             name: "usastate",
                             style:{width: "100%", height: "40px", fontsize: "20px"},
                             placeholder: "Select a State",
                             store: stateStore,
                             searchAttr: "name",
                             autocomplete: true
});
```

Comment: did u try added added below answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `fontsize` to `fontSize` and it will work.

```
var cboState = new ComboBox({
                          id: "usastate",
                          name: "usastate",
                          style:{width: "100%", height: "40px", fontSize: "20px"},
                          placeholder: "Select a State",
                          store: stateStore,
                          searchAttr: "name",
                          autocomplete: true
});
```

Or, you can also pass the `style` as a string:

```
var cboState = new ComboBox({
                          id: "usastate",
                          name: "usastate",
                          style:"width: '100%'; height: '40px'; font-size: '20px'",
                          placeholder: "Select a State",
                          store: stateStore,
                          searchAttr: "name",
                          autocomplete: true
});
```

Comment: thanks Himanshu for your response. sorry, neither of these worked for me?

Comment: here is the jsFiddle project. - https://jsfiddle.net/wgsl2005/Ld3zkerv/7/  the first way in your post worked but the second didn't work. But neither of them work in my dev box. is this feature version specific?

Comment: I don't think that it's version specific. I just can't figure out the reason as to why any of the above methods is not working for you. These is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have added running sample. along with added custom styles.

```js
require([
    "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory, ComboBox){
  var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
            {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
            {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
            {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
            {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
            {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
            {name:"California", id:"CA"},
            {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
            {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
            {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
        ]
    });
  
    var comboBox = new ComboBox({
      id: "usastate",
      name: "usastate",
      style:{width: "200px", height: "28px", fontSize: "20px"},
      placeholder: "Select a State",
      store: stateStore,
      searchAttr: "name",
      autocomplete: true
    }, "stateSelect").startup();
});
```

```html
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1"
            src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
<body class="claro">
    <input id="stateSelect">
</body>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***